# How to parse a splitted string item with use of lambda expression?

Tags: c#

I have this code in mind:

```
ForEachCommaSeperatedItemIn(myCommaSeparatedString, (item) => list.Add(item));
```

Where list is a List and myCommaSperatedString is a string with comma separated items (for example '12,14,15). The result should be that it 12,14 and 15 will be populated in list.

How should the signature be of `ForEachCommaSeperatedItemIn` ?

Comment: myCommaSeparatedString.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x => list.Add(x));

Comment: Since you are asking for opinions/discussion - it simply should *not be*... It is very likely you get CSV/JSON parsing wrong and would be better off using corresponding library to deal with input...

Comment: @Han `list.AddRange(myCommaSeparatedString.Split(','))` would be even simpler. This seems at least a little like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BlakeThingstad He asked lambda expression so I gave him that. Of course I prefer your method. Not everything should be written in lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature should be.

```
public void ForEachCommaSeperatedItemIn(string s, Action<string> f);
```

For example:

```
public void ForEachCommaSeperatedItemIn(string s, Action<string> f)
{
    string[] array = s.Split(',');
    foreach (string s in array)
    {
        f(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Converting enumerable to list feels... unnecessary?

Comment: Why create an unneeded list just to use `ForEach` instead of using `foreach` over the array you get from `Split`?

Comment: no conversion, string split returns string[]. This then just becomes a style / readability question. I like it like this

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way to do this, in a more functional style:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ForEachCommaSeperatedItemIn(string myCommaSeparatedString) 
        => myCommaSeparatedString.Split(',').ToList();
```